# how to avoid multiple rows populated in a join without using primarykey?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, left-join

I have a query like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT ,
 a.Type,
 a.Period,
 s.SiteCode,
 s.Name AS SiteName,
 s.StreetAddress,

 .........
FROM dbo.Anal AS a 
INNER JOIN  dbo.TankSystems AS ts ON a.TankSystemId = ts.TankSystemId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sites AS s ON ts.SiteId = s.SiteId 

Where s.SiteId=@SiteId
```

The above query returns the results as expected. eg: 3 rows.

I have another table as tanks with columns tankid,tank number,siteid,grade,diameter.
I want to return tanknumber with the left/inner join.

if i add ,

```
INNER/LEFt JOIN dbo.Tanks AS tt ON s.SiteId =tt.SiteId
```

The results are triples. Say, if I have 3 entries for a particular siteid in tanktable, I get 9 rows of results.
Here my issue is , i don't have any other column to restrict the join other than siteid.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "left inner join" - it's either a "left (outer) join" or an "inner join".

Comment: You don't say what rows you want as a function of base table rows and/or the business situation. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Constraints (including PKs & FKs) are not needed to query. It is necessary & sufficient to know what a row says about the business situation when in each base table & the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join onto another (additional) column in Tanks, or you need to collapse Tanks to one row per siteid.

Which you choose massively depends on what the requirements are. Let's say that Tanks lists the tanks on a Site and every site has a plastic tank and a metal tank and that's why there are two Tanks rows per site. Both tanks are made by the same manufacturer. You want the ID of the tank manufacturer. This means it doesn't matter which type  of tank you pick, you add the following join condition:

```
AND tt.TankType = 'plastic'
```

The query now discards all the metal tanks and you're down to one plastic tank per site, no doubling of the results (it's called a cartesian product) and you get your manufacturer name via the plastic tank.

Say instead you want to know the total capacity in litres of all the tanks on site, the plastic plus the metal. If you group and sum the capacities by siteid, you'll get rows where site id is unique:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT siteid, sum(capacity) as sumcap FROM tanks GROUP BY siteid) tt
ON tt.siteid = s.siteid
```

You've said you want tanknumber but what if there are multiple tank numbers on one site.. Do you want the lowest tank number? The highest? A comma separated list of all the tank numbers?

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT siteid, min(tanknumber) as firsttank FROM tanks GROUP BY siteid) tt
ON tt.siteid = s.siteid

INNER JOIN (SELECT siteid, max(tanknumber) as lasttank FROM tanks GROUP BY siteid) tt
ON tt.siteid = s.siteid

INNER JOIN (SELECT siteid, string_agg(tanknumber, ',') as tanklist FROM tanks GROUP BY siteid) tt
ON tt.siteid = s.siteid
```

These are all examples of how you can reduce the tanks list to a single siteid, and it's something you must do; decide what you want and ask the DB for it

#### Avoid using DISTINCT

There's usually no good reason for it. Definitely don't use it just to squash an unexpected load of duplicate looking rows that have appeared after you joined.

Don't have the database prepare twice the amount of rows it has to, then run an expensive process to filter out all the duplicates. Instead whenever adding a new table into a join, and you see the rows double up ask yourself what is it you really want out of that new table, and either restrict it so you only get what you want or group/aggregate it up so the info you want is condensed to single identifiers and doesn't cause your rows to double/triple/etc up

Comment: I understand. The tanks persite has unique tanknumber. It is a sequence. 1,2,3,4. Means 4 tanks in that site. All4 contain different fuel. So my requirement is retrun tank number as 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. The capacity or any other columns are not unique . Only the primary key and Tanknumber is unique in that table :(

Comment: You seem to be saying that any tank number will do, so just pick the MIN or the MAX as per my example, or if every site has a tanknumber 1 (but not every site will have even tank number 2 let alone 3 or 4), just add `AND tt.tanknumber = 1`. You aren't really saying what other info you want out of the tanks table so it's hard to give specific advice. *Why are you joining the tanks table in? What does "I want to return tanknumber" mean? Do you want the highest tank number? A list of tank numbers? The count of different fuels they contain?*

Comment: What does "right" tank number mean? right = correct? right = opposite of left? Please try to remember that you know what you want, I will only know what you want if you clearly explain it to me; I cannot read minds

Comment: I have added a picture of the result currently while doing with left join on tanks table with siteid restriction. You can see TankNumber column.how it populates. In ideal case Tank1 has to be PULP, Tank2 has to be Super, tank 3 has to be Unleaded

Comment: So you're saying that tank1 always stores PULP, tank2 always stores Super and tank3 always stores Unleaded, but the Tank table doesn't record this? The tank table SHOULD record this because it's part of the process of linking what's in a tank with what's on a site. If you really want to make the dubious decision of putting this data in code, then add a join condition of `AND ProductName = CASE tt.TankNumber WHEN 1 THEN 'PULP' WHEN 2 THEN 'Super' WHEN 3 THEN 'Unleaded' END`

Comment: It is not fixed. One site may have 3 tanks, another may have 5 tanks with different fuel. And I write query to return data from 1000s of sites.

Comment: Then you *MUST* record, in each tank row, what product is in that tank. If you do not store this information currently, it is mandatory that you upgrade the system so that it does record it

Comment: If we're punning... dbo.Anal, dbo.TankSystems, dbo.Sites, dbo.Tanks... are they septic tanks?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT ,
 a.Type,
 a.Period,
 s.SiteCode,
 s.Name AS SiteName,
 s.StreetAddress,
 s.CityOrLocal,
 tanks= STUFF((
 SELECT ', ' + [tank number] 
   FROM  dbo.Tanks tt 
   where tt.SiteId = s.SiteId  
   FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')   
FROM dbo.Analyses AS a 
INNER JOIN  dbo.TankSystems AS ts ON a.TankSystemId = ts.TankSystemId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sites AS s ON ts.SiteId = s.SiteId 

Where s.SiteId=@SiteId
```

Comment: This will return same TankNumber for all rows. That is TankNumber=1 for all 3 rows. It should be TankNumber 1 ,2,3

Comment: but this is only your criteria s.SiteId =tt.SiteId

Comment: Hmm..yes.but the requirment is as what I said..I cannot change schema..

Comment: which sql engine your are using and version?

Comment: mssql server 2012

Comment: you can aggregate tank_numbers so it will return in 1 field.